Do convergence rates for (convex) gradient descent apply when domain is (convex) subset of reals?
I have a convex multi-variate optimization problem where each variable lies on the domain $[x, \infty)$ for some positive number $x$.  I know the problem has a unique finite solution in the domain, and am interested in its convergence rate.
There are several convergence rates proven for Gradient Descent on convex problems (with Lipshitz gradient).  However I always see such rates given assuming the variables range over all the real numbers.
Do these rates still apply when the domain is restricted to a convex subset like I stated earlier?  In particular, does the $O(\frac{1}{\epsilon})$ rate of gradient descent apply?  I assume one needs to modify the algorithm to ensure the value does not get less than $x$ for this to apply.  I would assume it is something like: if $y^{t+1} = y^t - \mu^t \nabla y^t$ violates the $y \geq x$ condition then decrease $\mu^t$ until it no longer does, but would not be surprised if a more complicated sequence of step sizes is necessary for convergence.
If not, are there any conditions we could add to the problem to recover the convergence rate?
I assume that whatever the answer is will be a well-known (perhaps even trivial) result, but I have had a surprisingly difficult time finding a direct answer to this online, so any help would be appreciated.

Since these results are asymptotic, it's hard to see why there would be any problem applying them to arbitrary convex subsets except when the convergence is to the boundary.

I think your assumption is mistaken. Most algorithms I worked with handle simple constrains on domains by automatically transforming to an unconstrained $\mathbb{R}^n$ under the hood. For your specific case, the typical solution would be to have:
$$
y^\prime = \log (y - x)
$$
Now $y^\prime$ ranges over the whole real line and the optimizer will work with $y^\prime$ and compute gradients w.r.t $y^\prime$. If needed, the algorithm will automatically adjust the target to account for this transformation. Other transformation functions from $[x, \infty)$ to $\mathbb{R}$ are obviously possible as long as they are sufficiently well behaved.
So the convergence result will typically hold for this transformed (a.k.a. "unconstrained") variable.
There is also the whole field of constrained optimization which handles the cases when such a transformation is impossible/undesirable. This problem is however substantially harder in full generality, so if you can transform and use unconstrained optimization, it is typically preferable.
Some sources:

Parametrization cookbook by Jean-Benoist Leger
Stan manual on constraint transforms - those are used both for optimization as well as Bayesian inference
The notExp function in mgcv was designed to replace logarithm/exp in constraints and so discusses some background.

